# Copy table to attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, attribute-table, table

I have some tables with columns that I need to join/copy to another table, in case an attribute table. I was using join but I realized that it would be a better solution to add new fields to my initial table (attribute table) and then fill those fields with the columns that I need from the other tables than to join that tables into my initial table.
Is there any tool that does that? Copy a column from one table to another?
My problem is to distinguish the columns, I want to have specific names for each column, therefore I was thinking about create the fields and then fill them with the data from other tables.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...  Join the data to your layer making sure you're only joining the fields you wish to join.

Once that is done, export the layer to another copy.  Your joined data will follow.  This way you have your original layer and then another one with the joined information.  It should be quicker than having to manually or programmactically copy data from your joining tables to your layer's attribute table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm doing this in a model, so in the end I want to have my initial table without the joins or with the joins but with the column names that I want, because when I use join the columns's names are all the same, and I have different parameters that I need to distinguish.

Comment: So basically my problem is to distinguish the columns, I want to have specific names for each column, therefore I was thinking about create the fields and then fill them with the data from other tables.

Comment: **Edit your question with this info for other users to see.**  Also, add in answers to these.. How often will you need to do this?  If multiple times, are the parameters going to change.  Ex. Will there be different field names or different fields where the model would get the data from?  If this needs to be customizable, you may need to do a bit of python or other programming to accomplish what you want.

Comment: There are 4 columns that I want to fix the name but the values that will fill these columns will change every time I run the model

Comment: I believe something like that would take a more programmatic approach in order to accomplish.  Basically, you need something to be in the middle of this, like a table, to act as a translator. For instance, it would be 2 fields in your translator table, field 1 tells you the field name in the table, field 2 tells you the converted name.  It is more complex than can be expressed here, but I hope you can understand the gist of it.