# Copying fields between two layers in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, layers, attribute-table, copy

I have this attribute table (part of the whole attribute table) from one layer:

[image]

and this attribute table (part of the whole attribute table) from the second layer:

[image]

I try copy the cells value in fields: name2, source into the second layer:

[image]

Is there a way to do it in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3?

i can't do join because those two layers have no field with the same values.
i also red

- [Copying features from one layer into different layer using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136299/copying-features-from-one-layer-into-different-layer-using-arcgis-for-desktop)
- [Copy table to attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151134/copy-table-to-attribute-table)

Comment: May be you can export to csv and edit in text editor? Than back to arcgis. But i can hardly see the use of a table without an id. So what do you want to do with it?

Comment: What are you expecting to see in your output from this "copy"?

Comment: when working in a FGDB you could use the "load" function (this will also copy the shapes however).

Comment: Spatial join! maybe if you have a spatial relation. Or what about FID field to join them?

Comment: Try append tool

Comment: I still don't understand, what you mean. How do you know, which cells from table A go to which cells in table B? If you can't create a relation/join you only can append to the end of table B. This relation can be a logical  or a spatial expression. Otherwise you have to solve this manually.